# How to detect Tradingview the latest bar of each special session

Tags: pine-script

Below code highlight the first bar of each session every trade day.  How can I modify the code to only highlight the latest one (i.e. the session of today)?

```
study("First Bar", overlay=true)
period  = input("1", "Period", input.resolution)
inSession = not na(time(period, "0914-0915")[0])
colorOfBg = inSession ? color.red : na
bgcolor(color=colorOfBg, transp=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we:

- Add a `dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow)` condition to your `inSession`. `timenow` is the current time, so the condition is only true today.
- We use `color.new()` to generate your transparency so your code will work in v5 also:

```
//@version=4
study("First Bar", overlay=true)
period  = input("1", "Period", input.resolution)
inSession = not na(time(period, "0914-0915:1234567")) and dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow)
colorOfBg = inSession ? color.new(color.red, 60) : na
bgcolor(color=colorOfBg)
plotchar(inSession, "inSession", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```